# Multiple parameters with ternary operator

Tags: java, string, parameters

```
method(b ? "hello" : "hi", "whats", "going", "on");
```

When b == true what I get is is: **"hello", "whats", "going", "on";**

However what I actually want is:

```
method(b ? "hello" : ((((("hi", "whats", "going", "on"))))));
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: post your entire method

Comment: Is this a var-args method?

Comment: It's about the syntax - not about the functionality.
Yes - it is a var-args method.

Comment: and its a ternary operator. Plz don't call it parameter with question mark.

Comment: What's the signature of the var-args method?  Is it `method( String... args)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trenary operator must return the same type for both clauses (in your case, the "true" clause is a `String`, and it's unclear what is the "false" clause - but you probably want `String[]`).

You can partially solve it by always returning a `String[]`:

```
method(b?new String[] {"hello"}:new String[] {"hi", "whats", "going", "on"});
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I did was to blindly give it a shot in Eclipse, but obviously I could not get anything close to what you're asking for, so instead of just going with try/fail, I took a look at the [Java BNF grammar](http://cui.unige.ch/isi/bnf/JAVA/creating_expression.html) to see what is the shortest syntactically correct way to declare a collection without assignment to a variable.

Assuming that you are trying to avoid declaring extra variables but want the parameters created straight away, I would use the following, which in my humble opinion is the shortest and closest syntactically correct way to get what you want :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         boolean b = false;

         methodSample(b ? new String[]{"Hello"} : new String[]{"hi", "whats", "going", "on"});

    }

    public static void methodSample(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
    }

}
```

However, a cleaner way to do it would probably be :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean b = false;

    String[] val1 = {"hello"};
    String[] val2 = {"hi", "whats", "going", "on"};

    methodSample(b ? val1 : val2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for something like this

```
// change this value
var a=false;

var c =  a? "hello" : "\"hi\", \"whats\", \"going\", '\"on\"";

alert(c);

// or

var c =  a? ["hello"] : ["hi", "whats", "going", "on"];

alert(c[0]);
alert(c[1]);
alert(c[2]);
//.. an so on
```

----->>>>[Try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/jFsgj/)